# If y in range Python Error Catching

Tags: python-3.x

I seem to be having an issue with an error catch that I'm trying to implement in my code. Basically, if somebody writes something out of the scope from the range, I want my error message to show up. Otherwise, it'll just continue on with the program.
Here's the code.

```
n = 10

while True:
    id_usager = input("Entrer l'ID de l'usager pour lequel vous voulez une recommandation (entre 0 et {}): ".format(n-1))
    if id_usager in range(n):
        calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
        print("Pour la personne", id_usager, ", nous recommandons l'ami", recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite))
        continue
    else:
        print(id_usager)
        print("Erreur: l'usager doit être un nombre entier entre ", 0, "et", n - 1, "inclusivement.\n")
```

Comment: What exactly is the "issue" you're having?

Answer (score 1):

This breaks, because you do not cast `id_usager` to an integer. Checking if it's in the range only works if it's an integer.

You can use `s.isdigit()` to check if you can safely convert to an integer, and then `s = int(s)` to do the conversion.

** edited based on comment

Comment: Doing that, if I write for error catching purposes a str, it'll crash. I want it to handle the possibility of a STR by printing the message Erreur (Error)

Answer (score 0):

I found the trick.

```
    while True:
        id_usager = input("Entrer l'ID de l'usager pour lequel vous voulez une recommandation (entre 0 et {}): ".format(n - 1))

        if id_usager.isdigit():
            if int(id_usager) in range(n):
                id_usager = int(id_usager)
                calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
                print("Pour la personne", id_usager, ", nous recommandons l'ami", recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite))
                continue
            else:
                print("Erreur: l'usager doit être un nombre entier entre ", 0, "et", n - 1, "inclusivement.\n")

        else:
            print("Erreur: l'usager doit être un nombre entier entre ", 0, "et", n - 1, "inclusivement.\n")
```

This allows me to filter out the strings if there are in order to return an error message.